# Unable to write to FlatFile using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Hi i wanted to add a header to my flat file being generated so decided to add a header callback.But am getting the below error.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reportItemWriter' defined in 
    class    path resource [spring/batch/jobs/equity-eod-job.xml]:        
    Initialization of bean failed; nested 
    exception 
    is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 

    Failed to    convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8   

    implementing             

    org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,

    org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,
    org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamWriter,
    org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,
    org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,
    org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,
    org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type                                 org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter' 

    for property 'delegate'; nested exception is 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type       [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8 implementing 
   org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.spring  framework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStre  amWriter,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,org.springframework.aop.scope      .ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastr  uctureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework    .Advised] to required type      [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] for property    'delegate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at 
               org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.
    getObject
    (AbstractBeanFactory.java:331)

    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at                        
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.
    doGetBean
   (Abstract    BeanFactory.java:327)
    at    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.open(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Please help me:

My Step :

```
 <batch:step id="generateReport" next="sendMailStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reportReader" writer="reportItemWriter"
                 commit-interval="100">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Reader:

Writer:

```
<bean id="csvFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:./resources/#{jobParameters['REPORT']}"></property>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=","></property>
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names"
                        value="symbol,date,openPrice,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,trueRange,isInsideDayFormed,narrowRange"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
                    <property name="headerCallback" ref="reportItemWriter"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="reportItemWriter" class="com.equities.batch.ReportWriter" scope="step">
<property name="delegate" ref="csvFileWriter"></property>
</bean>
```

Report Writer :

```
package com.equities.batch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamSupport;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;

import com.equities.pojo.EodDataBean;

public class ReportWriter implements      ItemWriter<EodDataBean>,FlatFileHeaderCallback,ItemStream{

private FlatFileItemWriter<EodDataBean> delegate;


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback#writeHeader(java.io.Writer)
 */
public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.write("Script"+","+","+"Date"+","+"Open"+","+"High"+","+"Low"+","+"Close"+","+"True range"+","+"ID"+","+"NR");       
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter#write(java.util.List)
 */
public void write(List<? extends EodDataBean> items) throws Exception {
    this.delegate.write(items);     
}

/**
 * @return the delegate
 */
public ItemWriter<EodDataBean> getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
}

/**
 * @param delegate the delegate to set
 */
public void setDelegate(FlatFileItemWriter<EodDataBean> delegate) {
    this.delegate =  delegate;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream#open(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext)
 */
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
        throws ItemStreamException {
    delegate.open(executionContext);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream#update(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext)
 */
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext)
        throws ItemStreamException {
    delegate.update(executionContext);

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream#close()
 */
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    delegate.close();

}

}
```

if I remove the ItemStream and set the writer as ItemStream , i get the below error.

```
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing step generateReport in job     eodBatchJob
rg.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open  
before it can be written to
at 

org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write
(FlatFileItemWriter.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why ReportWriter  implements ItemWriter and ItemStream? Please remove them and remove delegates also. Keep only FlatFileHeaderCallback. It will work

Answer (score 3):

When Beans in Spring are defined, they can often be constructed as a Proxy, not as a real instance of the defined class.

This, for example, happens in your code for bean "csvFileWriter" because it is defined with scope "step". Spring will only create a proxy for it and will postpone the real construction of the instance to the point where the step actually is executed.

The problem is that your "setDelegate" expects a FlatFileItemWriter, however, it only gets a proxy and not an instance of a class that actually is "FlatFileItemWriter" or a derived from "FlatFileItemWriter".

The Proxy classes can "mock" implemented interfaces of a class, but they cannot mock the class itself. In your example, the proxy can pretend to be an "ItemWriter", "ItemStream", and an "ItemStreamWriter", since this interfaces are actually implemented by FlatFileItemWriter, however, as mentioned, it cannot pretend to be a "FlatFileItemWriter".

Therefore, if you change the following in your ReportWriter, the code should work:

```
public class ReportWriter implements      ItemWriter<EodDataBean>,FlatFileHeaderCallback,ItemStream{

    private ItemStreamWriter<EodDataBean> delegate;

    /**
     * @param delegate the delegate to set
     */
    public void setDelegate(ItemStreamWriter<EodDataBean> delegate) {
        this.delegate =  delegate;
    }

   ...
```

However, there is no reason to create your own "ReportWriter" and set a delegate. Instead, just define a ReportHeaderCallBack class and use this to configure headercallback in the FlatFileItemWriter:

```
public class ReportHeaderCallBack implements FlatFileHeaderCallback {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback#writeHeader(java.io.Writer)
     */
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
         writer.write("Script"+","+","+"Date"+","+"Open"+","+"High"+","+"Low"+","+"Close"+","+"True range"+","+"ID"+","+"NR");       
    }  
}

<bean id="csvFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" ... ></property>

    <property name="lineAggregator" ...></property>

    <property name="headerCallback">
      <bean class="com.equities.batch.ReportHeaderCallBack"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I guess, that is also the solution Nghia Do suggested in his comment.